# How do I figure out what database connections are open at any one time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, concurrency, database-connection, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running a single-threaded Rails 5.0 application through the "rails console", with the below configuration in `config/database.yml` for my development environment:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: sims 
  username: postgres
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 15000
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

Invariably, running my code below will eventually die with a "Could not obtain a connection" error:

```
  pool = Concurrent::FixedThreadPool.new(1) 
  promises = links.map do |link| 
    Concurrent::Promise.execute(executor: pool) do
      result = process_link(link) 
      if result
        if result.kind_of?(Array) 
          result.each do |my_obj|
            my_obj.update_attributes({ :a => a }) 
            records_processed = records_processed + my_obj.matches.count 
          end
        else
          records_processed = records_processed + result.matches.count 
          result.update_attributes({ :a => a }) 
        end
      end
    end
  end
  promises.map(&:wait).map(&:value!)
```

How can I figure out what connections are not being closed, or what queries are still running that would cause this to occur? I am baffled because nowhere should concurrent queries be running at once.

```
Error during processing: (ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError) could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.003 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:202:in `block in wait_poll'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `loop'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `wait_poll'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:154:in `internal_poll'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:278:in `internal_poll'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:148:in `block in poll'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:158:in `synchronize'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:148:in `poll'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:717:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:490:in `checkout'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info from PostgreSQL with:

```
SELECT * from pg_stat_activity;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm running a single-threaded Rails 5.0 application

As soon as your application code creates another thread (which it is doing via `Concurrent::FixedThreadPool.new(1)`), it is no longer a 'single-threaded application'.

> How can I figure out what connections are not being closed or what queries are still running that would cause this to occur.

To inspect the connections that are not being closed, you can access the current connection pool's list of connections via  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.connections`, which will return an Array of [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractAdapter.html) objects you can examine. For example, to `inspect` the thread `owner` of each connection currently in the connection pool, you can run:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.connections.map(&:owner).map(&:inspect)
```

> I am baffled because nowhere should concurrent queries be running at once.

Your assumption that concurrent queries are running because the connection pool is being exhausted is not correct. On how to fix this issue, refer to my answer to your other (very similar) question, [Does concurrency happen even when only one thread is in a thread pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42129072/2518355)